# Custom "Rails Port" (openstreetmap-website) implemention, Ruby-on-Rails "Authenticity Token" problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openstreetmap

I am not trained nor experienced in Ruby-on-Rails. I am a hobbyist developer trying to implement a customization of the [openstreetmap-website](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website). So far much of it is working well, and I'm happy with the result.

It is running here: https://opengeofiction.net

This is a reimplementation of a site that has been active since 2012. We have about 200 active users. The former developer decided to abandon the site so I and a group of users have been working to host it.

Most aspects of the site are working fine, but my users keep seeing two issues (I'm guessing they are related) which is driving us all crazy:

- "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken" errors
- frequent random forced logouts while navigating the site

I think I more-or-less understand what the Authenticity Tokens are and what they're trying to do, but that doesn't help me to even troubleshoot the problem, given I am not an experienced Rails developer.

Can anyone make any suggestions of places to look for answers (either within the application itself, or online forums)?

**Is there a way to disable, site-wide, the Authenticity Token system?** I don't think it's necessarily needed for a hobbyist site without anything much at stake.

I tried a way I found, a kind of "per controller" disabling of the tokens, using this line at the top of each of the controller pages:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

This made the ActionController error disappear, but made the forced logout problem worse.

Perhaps the forced logout problem is unrelated? I don't think so, though.

Please be forgiving in your responses. I have worked as a SQL coder and database developer in the past, but this "front end" stuff is pretty much alien to me.

The website is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS virtual server. I downloaded a commit of the openstreetmap-website code in late May. Happy to append any other information if people have suggestions for what's relevant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First thought is rather than `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in every controller, you can instead remove `protect_from_forgery :with => :exception` from the `ApplicationController` [Here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L6) now why you would want to do this or why this is occurring I cannot say without really delving into the code base (which unfortunately I am unable to do at the moment) although [Here](https://blog.nvisium.com/understanding-protectfromforgery) is a blog post that migth help.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to my one responder, for their suggestion. As it turned out, we didn't get so far as to try that, because we found out the underlying problem.

Apparently, the openstreetmap-website ("rails port") expects that a production instance will have a tool called *memcache* installed. It was another member of our team who figured this out, so I don't have the details, but I think that's enough of a hint if someone finds this question in the future and is trying to solve the issue.

Although we are still running the "rails port" as a development instance (rather than production), we are doing so as a de facto production instance, with 100's of active users.

This level of deployment requires *memcache* to manage the authenticity tokens, I guess.

If I get more details from my colleague about specific steps he took, I'll amend this answer.

Meanwhile, our site is up and running quite well, now.